# Render image of exact size as that of original image on surface view in rajawali android

Tags: android, rajawali

I have an image. I want to render the image with the same size on surface view.

But the image size changes while rendering on surface view.

I am initializing the plane in rajawali as under:

```
 Plane back;
 SimpleMaterial background = new SimpleMaterial();
 back = new Plane(1,1,1,1);
 back.setMaterial(background);
 back.addTexture(mTextureManager.addTexture(bg)); // bg is the bitmap image
 addChild(back);
```

I read the link below but i didn't understand much.

[Relation between plane size and image dimensions](https://github.com/Rajawali/Rajawali/issues/1031)

Can anyone specify what should be the parameters of this plane so that size of image remains the same as that of the original image.

Comment: I have the same question

Answer (score 1):

From the issue link that you have posted got the clue.
I have changed the RajawaliRenderer.java class and instead of the mCamera which is of Camera Type object,just replaced it with the Camera2D class.

Usage:

```
Bitmap texture = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.mContext.getResources(), ResourceId);
        planeMat.addTexture(this.mTextureManager.addTexture(texture));
        Plane plane = new Plane(1.0f, 1.0f, 1, 1);
        plane.setRotZ(-90.0f);
        //plane.setScale(2.8f);
        plane.setMaterial(planeMat);
        addChild(plane);
```